# can't pass autoID to new VC

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to pass the received autoID to another ViewController...
I'm getting the ID like this:

```
var passID: String = ""

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    jobsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "userID").queryEqual(toValue: userID).observe(.childAdded, with: {snapshot in
        let currentPostID = snapshot.key
        self.passID = currentPostID
        print(self.passID) //-> Here the ID gets printed correctly
    })
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toJobDetail", sender: indexPath)
}
```

My Segue itself looks like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toJobDetail" {
        if let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath, let nextVC = segue.destination as? MyProfileJobDetailViewController {
            nextVC.jobDetails = MyProfileJobDetailViewController.JobDetails(IDPassed: self.passID)
   }}}
```

and I try to print the ID in the New VC like this:

```
var jobDetails: JobDetails?
struct JobDetails {
    var IDPassed: String
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(jobDetails?.IDPassed) -> ID won't get printed correctly 
 }
```

But my Output now only is:

**Optional(())**

Am I doing something wrong with passing the ID?
Because printing the ID when selecting the cell works....

EDIT:

I'm now getting the ID as I just call the performSegue inside the Firebase Query:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    jobsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "userID").queryEqual(toValue: userID).observe(.childAdded, with: {snapshot in
        let currentPostID = snapshot.key
        self.passID = currentPostID
        print(self.passID)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toJobDetail", sender: indexPath)
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you try removing the struct and declare a simple var variable and assign value. I think that will solve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is async and takes some time, you should ensure you have the required value before moving to the next screen. try this..

```
jobsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "userID").queryEqual(toValue: userID).observe(.childAdded, with: {snapshot in
    let currentPostID = snapshot.key
    self.passID = currentPostID
    print(self.passID) //-> Here the ID gets printed correctly
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toJobDetail", sender: indexPath)
})
```

EDIT:

try something...

```
var jobDetails: JobDetails? {
   didSet {
      print("set jobDetails to \(jobDetails)"
   }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("viewDidLoad: \(jobDetails?.IDPassed)")
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer - sadly, now I get **Optional("")** as the output... do I maybe need to change something on the second vc?

Comment: I've made an edit, can you try that in your second view controller and let me know hte output

Comment: Tried out your Edited solution and get **viewDidLoad: Optional("")** and **Optional("")** as an output

Comment: viewDidLoad is being called before you set the value. So the view is loading in prepareForSegure and you are printing out the value which is empty. in in the next line in prepareForSegue you are setting the value. you might be better using viewWillAppear or didSet on the property

Comment: Ok I did something completely new (check my updated code) - I'm getting the ID want to pass but only behind a **Optional**, so right my output looks like **Optional("ID")** - is there a way to remove the Optional part?

Comment: ok nevermind I just needed to force unwrap the value - but thank you for your help though